# How to play multiple Media Elements in Windows Phone 8/8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to my app play four sounds together, and I have four MediaElements. When I run app, for the best only three of four sounds play.

```
MediaElement sound1 = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/sound1.mp3"), AutoPlay = false };
MediaElement sound2 = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/sound2.mp3"), AutoPlay = false };
MediaElement sound3 = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/sound3.mp3"), AutoPlay = false };
MediaElement backgroundMusic = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/backgroundMusic .mp3"), AutoPlay = true, Volume = 1, IsLooping = true };
```

backgroundMusic must play always and sound1, sound2, sound3 must play after tapping button.

Answer (score 2):

MediaElements class plays only one sound at a time, you have to use SoundEffect class.

1st: Add Reference (Microsofot.Xna.Framework) to your project.

2nd: you need to add this two classes in youe page.xaml

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
```

3rd: Try this code.

```
public partial class Testing : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    SoundEffect Sound1;
    SoundEffect Sound2;
    public Testing()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

   // Load the sound file
    StreamResourceInfo Sound1 = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/sound1.mp3", UriKind.Relative));      

    StreamResourceInfo Sound2 = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/sound1.mp3", UriKind.Relative));

    Sound1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(Sound1.Stream);
    Sound2 = SoundEffect.FromStream(Sound2.Stream);
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

    }

    private void Sound1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Sound1.Play();
        Sound2.Play();
    }
}
```

Make Sure that Add the sound files is set as to **Content** for this just select song and goto its property, you will find build action over there change its value to "Content".

Comment: I'm trying, but it gives an error: 
cannot resolve symbol StreamResourceInfo

Comment: Try VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Suspend button and Resume again (no need to close the window). This works in my case